# CSS fluid design issue

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am planning a fluid-design based layout with 2 cols as follows;

[image]

Below is the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="fl wd5percent"><img src="titleText.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="fl wd95percent"></div>
</div>
```

Here the 1st col contains the image for title text and remaining width is used for other content.

Now my issue is as this is a fluid layout, I cannot use "px" width anywhere... I define `img` to use `max-width:100%`, but that kind of creates blank space (or gap) below the titleText image when the 2nd col height is more.

How do I define my CSS such that the page scales well as the browser is resized. By that, I mean whatever be the browser size, the titleText image would be displayed to occupy full height as the content height of 2nd col..

**Again, I cannot use px width or height anywehere in my CSS. So I cannot say, width:200px;height:100px**

Comment: I guess I did not quite see it...So is the -1 vote for that ?

Comment: @Wex : Did you vote the question down and if yes, why if I may know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/xKrws/2/

Comment: Thx a lot...But I do not see the effect on the jsfiddle..Also even though I would prefer to use text for the 1st col, it is rotated text..so not sure if it would work as expected even with CSS transforms..

Comment: Thx...Since you have used text for the 1st col...i am not sure how well it would adjust if I use a image (rotated text) instead..

Comment: Yes right...now when u have used the image...and if I reduce the browser size, the image kind of crops at lower sizes...I want it to scale lower/higher as per browser sizes..

Comment: I don't think that can be done in css. you can try this link: http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/quick-tip-resizing-images-based-on-browser-window-size/ -

Comment: Actually I am not just looking at using flexible images, but images that scale alongwith other content...